# Template tag doesn't respect passed context variable

Tags: python, django

I'm having an issue with my custom template tag not respecting passed context variable. So, I have a template named `task_list.html`, which includes `paginator.html` that references my custom template tag (`{% url_replace %}`):

`task_list.html`:

```
...
{% include 'paginator.html' with page_obj=tasks_tomorrow page='page_tomorrow' %}
...
```

`paginator.html`:

```
...
<a class="page-link" href="?{% url_replace page=page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}" 
...
```

However, the URL constructed is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo/?page=2`, instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo/?page_tomorrow=2`.

This is my template tag:

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_replace(context, **kwargs):
    query = context['request'].GET.dict()
    query.update(kwargs)
    return urlencode(query)
```

What is the issue here?